# @StateObject on iOS 13

Tags: swift, swiftui

We realized today that our app was targeting iOS 14, and changed it to iOS 13.
We found out we are not able to use `StateObject` on iOS 13, and some problems arose. This is what we have:

`AlertState.swift`

```
final class CardState: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = CardState()

    @Published var shouldShowCard = false
    
    private init() {}
    
    // Some other methods and variables
}
```

Then, we use it like this:

`ContentView.swift`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var cardState = CardState.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            if cardState.shouldShowCard {
                Card()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Card.swift`

```
struct Card: View {
    @StateObject var cardState = CardState.shared

    var body: some View {
        // View
    }
}
```

`AlertState` holds more data, such as the text we show in the card. The card can be triggered from any screen of the app.

So, we targeted iOS 13 and replaced `StateObject` with `ObservedObject`, but then it stopped animating when the card gets hidden by switching `shouldShowCard` to `false`, the View just disappears.
What should we use in order to achieve what we used to have when using `StateObject`? We are a bit lost and tried everything we found.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you might be able to get away with doing `@State var cardState = CardState.shared` inside `ContentView`

Comment: Also I think inside `CardView`, you should have `ObservedObject` instead of `StateObject` for both iOS 13 and 14

Comment: @aheze Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, that did not work. If I set `cardState` as `State` the screen does not update when the value of `shouldShowCard` is toggled.

Comment: Since it is a singleton Inject it as an `@EnvironmentObject` In the ContentView. Card().environmentObject(CardState.shared)

Answer (score 1):

Here's possible solution. We are wrapping `ObservedObjects` in a views with `@State`.

```
struct ViewModelWrapper<V: View, ViewModel: ObservableObject>: View {
    private let contentView: V
    @State private var contentViewModel: ViewModel

    init(contentView: @autoclosure () -> V, vm: @autoclosure () -> ViewModel) {
        self._contentViewModel = State(initialValue: vm())
        self.contentView = contentView()
    }

    var body: some View {
        contentView
            .environmentObject(contentViewModel)
    }
}
```

`@State` preserves model object from recreation while `.environmentObject` allows to pass exactly the same model every time view re-renders.